# How can I remove scripts that run by default when I open the Linux terminal? (WSL)

Tags: linux, windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I accidentally created a script that runs automatically when I open the linux terminal on windows.
I completely forgot where I created these files and now I am stumped on how to remove them.

Is there anyway I can remove these scripts or have the Linux terminal be reset to default settings?

I am using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

[Terminal with automatic scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nQ9k.png)

Comment: Check ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is how to [find-out-what-scripts-are-being-run-by-bash-on-startup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334382/find-out-what-scripts-are-being-run-by-bash-on-startup). That link answers that question but here is the short of it:

To find all of them you could run:

```sh
echo exit | strace bash -li |& grep '^open'
```

(`-li` means login shell interactive; use only `-i` for an interactive non-login shell.)
This will show a list of files which the shell opened or tried to open. On many systems, they are as follows:

Also it's good to know that by default the following are usually run:

1. `/etc/profile`
2. `/etc/profile.d/*` (various scripts in /etc/profile.d/)
3. `/home/<username>/.bash_profile`
4. `/home/<username>/.bash_login`
5. `/home/<username>/.profile`
6. `/home/<username>/.bashrc`
7. `/home/<username>/.bash_history` (Not a script. Simply enables `history` command)
8. `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`
9. `/etc/bash_completion.d/*`
10. `/etc/inputrc` (defines key bindings; this is not a script)

FYI: `/home/<username>/` is the same as `~` on most systems

---

For each of the scripts mentioned above you may want to check if they are calling yet another script... An easy way to do that is to grep all of those scripts for keywords implying they are calling another script (although `strace` will already show that)

You may want to:

```
cat <script_name> | grep -e 'bash' -e 'source' -e '\.\/'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the WSL terminal, I would try to check if you are calling a startup file in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. These are typical dotfiles that are called when a new BASH session is started. In your case, look for a call to `/bin/brew` (or a line that may potentially call brew) in these files.